# call TCP listener on application start

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, tcp, tcpclient

I have a tcp listener in my web application which accepts connection and receives data from many devices.
I want this tcp listener to start when application life cycle start.. 
I will try to explain the scenario here.
Suppose I have 10 pages in my web app with different functionalities and a master page.

> 1. After login TCP listener should get started to connect and receive data from devices.
> 2. If user is on status page or control page(status and control page are related to device function controls directly) the pages's data
>      should be updated, whenever listener receives any data from client
>      devices.
> 3. If user is on any other page doing some other task and tcp listener from backend received some trigger like some alarm because it should
>      run all the time in backend and receive data, so it should show an
>      alert whether user is on what ever page.

So what should I do for that?
Should I make use of library file in Global.asax.cs.

Its like listener methods should run all the time and return data received but I will catch the data from listener whenever I want.

How can I achieve that? Any advice or direction is appreciated.

Is it possible by making web service. if yes then also how can I use a webservice this way?

Comment: You should not have long-lived services (like a socket listener) in an ASP.NET application (or web-applications in general, IMO) because the web-application host (i.e. IIS) can and will reset your application code at-will, with no warning. You should run your socket server inside a separate process running as a dedicated Windows Service and use some form of IPC to communicate with your ASP.NET application.

Comment: yes.. I have searched and got some thing like that but then also I thought it is no harm to ask with specific conditions if there is any other way then windows service. But yes thank you I will start working that way.

Comment: But with this also I think the problem remains same. How will I show alert on web page if windows service receives any value from device to trigger the alarm . Its the windows service that should interrupt my web app when it get certain value

Answer (score 0):

this is a long due answer. With the advice of **@Dai** ....
**The answer here is using SignalR and a Windows Service.** 
I will create a windows service to open a tcp connection and it will communicate with database whenever it receives data.
Then SignalR from my web page will be monitoring the database and whenever any updation happens in database it will update on web page.